# Write given expression as a convolution

Tags: combinatorics

There are a functions: $f(i,j;a)$ and $f(i,j;b)$

Let $A$, $B$ be a finite sets.

Let's define new functions:
$F(A, B, a)=\prod_{i\in A, j\in B}f(i,j;a)$ and $F(A, B, b)=\prod_{i\in A, j\in B}f(i,j;b)$

> express $\prod_{i\in A, j\in B}(f(i,j;a)+f(i,j;b))$ in terms of $F(C,D,a)$ and $F(C',D';b)$, where $C,C',D,D'$ are some sets

This question comes from following obserwation: if
$F(A, a)=\prod_{i\in A}g(i,a)$
Then $\prod_{i\in A}(g(i,a)+g(i,b))=\sum_{C\cup D=A}F(C,a)F(D,b)$

Is it possible to do simillar thing?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you replace "$A$" in your observation with $A \times B$ and $g((i,j), a)$ with $f(i, j; a)$, you get

$$\prod_{i\in A, j\in B}(f(i,j;a)+f(i,j;b)) = \prod_{(i,j) \in A\times B}(f(i,j;a)+f(i,j;b)) = \sum_{P \subseteq A\times B}F(P,a)F(A\times B \setminus P,b)$$

The problem is, $P$ will not always be $C \times D$ for some $C\subseteq A, D \subseteq B$. For example, if $B = A$, then one subset $P$ would be the diagonal $\{a \times a\mid a\in A\}$.

Even when $P = C\times D$, $A\times B \setminus P$ will not be another product of subsets unless either $C = A$ or $D = B$.

So, no, you cannot write the product in terms of just $F(C,D; a), F(C',D'; b)$.